# Javascript Regexp for all numeric and decimal point format

Tags: javascript, regex

i'd like to make a javascript validation that will accept all numeric and decimal point format.

For example :
1,000,000.00 is OK
1.000.000,00 is OK

1.000,000.00 is not OK
1.000,000,00 is not OK
1,000.000,00 is not OK
1,000.000.00 is not OK

Based on what i got here is :
`/^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})?$/` is only valid for 1,000,000.00 not for 1.000.000,00

How can i validate both format ?

**Updated :**

What if the thousand points are not compulsory such as :
1000000.00 is OK or
1000000,00 is OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to look at a regular expression this big is to blow it up to 
a very large font and split it on the alternatives (|)

```
var s='1,000,000.00';// tests

var result= /(^\d+([,.]\d+)?$)/.test(s) || // no thousand separator

/((^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+(\.\d+)?)$)/.test(s) || // comma thousand separator

/((^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})+(,\d+)?)$)/.test(s); // dot thousand separator

alert(result)
```

Put together its a brute-

```
function validDelimNum2(s){
var rx=/(^\d+([,.]\d+)?$)|((^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+(\.\d+)?)$)|((^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})+(,\d+)?)$)/;
return rx.test(s);
}
```

**//tests**

```
var N= [
'10000000',
    '1,000,000.00',
    '1.000.000,00',
    '1000000.00',
    '1000000,00',
    '1.00.00',
    '1,00,00',
    '1.000,00',
    '1000,000.00'
]
var A= [];
for(var i= 0, L= N.length; i<L; i++){
    A.push(N[i]+'='+validDelimNum2(N[i]));
}
A.join('\n')

/*  returned values
10000000=true
1,000,000.00=true
1.000.000,00=true
1000000.00=true
1000000,00=true
1.00.00=false
1,00,00=false
1.000,00=true
1000,000.00=false
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex that you want..

```
^(([1-9]\d{0,2}(((\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?)|((,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)))|(0(\.|,)\d{1,2})|([1-9]\d+((\.|,)\d{1,2})?))$
```

This is the link that proves that it can handles all cases

http://regexr.com?2tves

Comment: That's not what @Siwan __wants__, it's what he already __has__ (just shortened); And yet his version is more specific (see first digit and decimal digits)

Comment: @Gursel Koca, is 0 valid if i use that regexp ?

Comment: what if i validate 1000 ? is that also valid ? :)

Comment: it should not be valid, it should be written as 1,000. or you should say that comma is not compulsory..

Comment: @siwan , I have corrected . you can use first regex. but comma or dot is compulsory

Comment: @siwan, final regex all you want has been met. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the decimal part and thousands separators are mandatory, not optional, and that 0 is not an allowed value (as suggested by your examples and your regex):

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}|(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})$
```

As a verbose regex:

```
^              # Start of string
[1-9]\d{0,2}   # 1-3 digits, no leading zero
(?:            # Match either...
 (?:,\d{3})*   # comma-separated triple digits
 \.\d{2}       # plus dot-separated decimals
|              # or...
 (?:\.\d{3})*  # dot-separated triple digits
 ,\d{2}        # plus comma-separated decimals
)              # End of alternation
$              # End of string
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (though not most elegant by far) method would be to write analogous RE for another case and join them with 'OR', like this:

```
/^(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]{2})?)|([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]{2})?))$/
```

**UPDATE**

A little cleaned up version

```
/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(((,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?)|((\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})?))$/
```

Comment: Yes, that'll work. Thanks mkilmanas, but is there another shorter way ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `,` and `\.` with `[,.]` to accept either in either location.  It would also make `1,000.000.00` OK though.

Its harder to make the regexp behave like that in JavaScript because you can't use lookbehinds

```
/^(0|0[.,]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{0,2}((,(\d{3}))*(\.\d{2})?|(\.(\d{3}))*(,\d{2})?))$/

/^      #anchor to the first char of string
(       #start group
  0       # 0
|       # or
  0[.,]   # 0 or 0 followed by a . or ,
  \d{2}   # 2 digits
|       # or
  [1-9]   #match 1-9
  \d{0,2} #0-2 additional digits
  (       #start group
    (,(\d{3}))* # match , and 3 digits zero or more times
    (\.\d{2})?  # match . and 2 digits zero or one
  |       # or
    (\.(\d{3})* # match . and 3 digits zero or more times
    (,\d{2})?   # match , and 2 digits zero or one time
  )       #end group
)       #end group
$/      #anchor to end of string
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AC3Bm/